# Concatenating date and time in React Native returns 'Invalid Date'

Tags: javascript, datetime, react-native, momentjs

I have two fields in my React-Native app, one for date and one for time. The date field returns a value of the format 'YYYY-MM-DD' and the time field returns a value of the format 'hh:mm A'.I'm using moment for format conversions. The final API call should be made with a single entry of the format 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm', So to concatenate date and time I use,

```
moment(date+ " "+time).format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss")
```

It works fine in my simulators both Android and iOS and also when I debug on a device but as soon as I take builds for both it starts returning

> Invalid Date.

**EDIT :** Tried `moment(date + " " + value).format();`, also returns 'Invalid Date' in builds. 
Also tried doing it directly using `Date` `new Date(date+ " " + time);` without giving any formats, also returns 'Invalid Date' in the build.

Comment: how if you change this one `("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss")` to this `("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")` ?

Comment: @RizalSidik That is the format that I'm supposed to use in my API calls. But I tried alerting each value in a build and found I'm getting 'Invalid Date' even if I give `moment(date + " " + value).format();`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use [`moment(String, String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) since your input is neither in ISO 8601 nor in RFC 2822 format.

As [`moment(String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/) states:

> When creating a moment from a string, we first check if the string matches known ISO 8601formats, we then check if the string matches the RFC 2822 Date time format before dropping to the fall back of `new Date(string)` if a known format is not found.
>
> For consistent results parsing anything other than ISO 8601 strings, you should use String + Format.

In your case you can use:

```
moment(date+ " "+time, "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm a").format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss")
```

Comment: Thanks mate.! It works like a charm. But do you know why it only occurs in builds and not in the emulator.

Comment: @DanPhilip you're welcome! I don't know exactly why it only occurs in the build, probably because string parsing is environment dependent, as stated in the [linked doc](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/).